# handling link error with secondary .cpp and .h

Tags: c++, header, lnk2005

First, the code snippets I'm having issues with;

settings.h

```
   namespace
{
int WINDOW_WIDTH;
int WINDOW_HEIGHT;
bool FULLSCREEN;
}

void settings_init();
```

settings.cpp

```
#include "DX_Constants.h"

void settings_init()
{
 WINDOW_WIDTH = 1920;
 WINDOW_HEIGHT = 1080;
 FULLSCREEN = true;

}
```

main.cpp     //just the important part..i haven't forgotton the other pieces needed by winapi

```
#include "settings.h"

int WINAPI WinMain(...)
{
settings_init();

if(//verifies values entered are seen here correctly ...NOTE triggers on != )
return false;


....code continues
}
```

my problems:

1. running the code in this format triggers the if statement check and closes   the program.
2. if i remove the namespace anonymous i get LNK 2005 errors for the variables.
3. I CAN get the code to run if i simply comment out ALL of settings.cpp and put the function definition into the header file, but this is a shortfix to me.

what I need: obviously more understanding about header and secondary .cpp files...and probably linking. I have a couple books; "programming 2d games" by kelly, "beginning game programming" by harbour, and "visual C++ 2010" by horton. can someone point me in the direction of a place to learn in more detail my problem, which is getting the functions to live in .cpp while the declarations live in the header, or recommend a book that will teach me to understand these issues?

Solution edit: Credit goes to Mats Petersson (see the comments)

solution for the code ended up being;

1. remove the anonymous namespace and brackets.
2. apply extern prefix in front of the global variable type declarations in settings.h .
3. ADD normal global variable declaration ( ex. int window_width; ) to the settings.cpp file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The names `WINDOW_HEIGHT` and `WINDOW_WIDTH` are likely used as macros or other names in the Windows environment. Using variables that are all upper-case names is generally a bad idea, as this is the convention for macros, so the chances of accidentally conflicting with some macro defined in some header-file that you didn't even know was being included is much greater.

I would suggest that you change the names of your variables so that they don't conflict - the simple way to do that is to use lower-case names, `window_height` and `window_width`, etc.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, same errors and issues, the lnk 2005 error that i mentioned in 2. is more specifficially error LNK2005: "int window_width" (?window_width@@3HA) already defined in settings.obj

Comment: That sounds like you are compiling and linking the same source twice, which I think is because you should be having `extern` in front of the name, and then a second declaration of the same names in `settings.cpp` (without `extern`). Otherwise, you do get one copy of the variables for every source file that includes the header, which isn't what you want.

Comment: And of course, the fact that you have two copies is also why your code goes wrong, since `main` is reading the "wrong copy". I'll come back and edit the answer in a bit, but I'm off to have some breakfast now...

Comment: That did it! Thank you. I'm used to working with class declarations and prototyping in the header and then the functions existing in the .cpp. I did not realize that global variables acted different. If I want to learn more about this "extern" prefix any hints as to where I should begin looking?